# Redirect from non-www http to https with www

Tags: apache, http, redirect, mod-rewrite, https

I'm trying to redirect our old site from http to https and from a non-www to www at the same time. We have currently a lot of link that we have acquired over the years with the non www & http version of the site and I want to reduce the amount of redirects, since don't want to be diluted by "link-juice". We also have links from https// non-www and http//www :/

Currently the redirect schema looks like this:

http: //domain.com/oldpage.html
**301 Moved Permanently**
https: //domain.com/oldpage.html
**301 Moved Permanently**
https: //www.domain.com/newpage.html
**200 OK**

Is there a workaround to get one 301 redirect less? 
For example like this: 
 http//domain.com/oldpage.html -> to https://www.domain.com/newpage.html

Comment: Sure, that's entirely possible.

Answer (score 1):

**This is what you want in your `.htaccess`**

Only 1 redirect, regardless if it's insecure (http), apex (www-less) or both:

```
# canonical redirect http → https ( with optional www complection)
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

# https:// apex →  https:// www.*
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?!www\.)example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Would have been great if your solution would be generic (without hard coding a domain in it).

Answer (score 0):

yes and it's easy to understand
run regular expression over any URL of request that match the prefered form which is

> https://www.

like in javascript `/^https:\/\/www\..*$/.exec(url)`
if this returned non null value 
thats mean the url folow the https & www form

else if one of them vaiolats your rules like http or non www url or all of them
parse the url and extract the path only then append it to your perfect url

```
var redirectURL = "https://www.yourDomain.com"+path;
```

And then send redirect request to this perfect form.

from this request:

> http://yourDomain.com/something

redirect to new URL

> https://www.yourDomain.com/something

just in one redirect response

Comment: Many thanks to both of you. Would this also work from another .domain as well? We have another group level site using another domain ending. We want to pass some pages to the current site with one redirect. 

Does this mean we can use settings like this on the group site.        

ServerName domain.a
ServerAlias www.domain.a
Redirect permanent / https://www.domain.b 

And then specify the group url on site b. with a simple.
Redirect 301 /old-page/ https://www.domain.b/new-page/

Comment: the easier way is:  in .a domain on known pages you want to redirect just extract the path and append it to the perfect prefix "https://www.domain.b"+path and ask for redirect to this perfect URL even you can change the path to the corresponding path in .b server if it's different

Answer (score 0):

```
   NameVirtualHost *:80
   <VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName example.com
   ServerAlias www.example.com
   RedirectPermanent / https://www.example.com
   </VirtualHost>

   <VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName example.net
   ServerAlias www.example.net
   DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example.net
   RedirectMatch "old-page$" "https://www.example.com/new-page”
   </VirtualHost>

   <VirtualHost *:443>
   ServerName www.example.com
   ...
   </VirtualHost>
```

Ref: https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RedirectSSL